# ¿Como abro o descargo un archivo con dirección de blob?

Tags: c#, jquery, .net, excel

Lo que quiero hacer es cargar un excel con cierta información mediante un input type=file, hasta ahí todo bien pero sin embargo necesito guardar temporalmente el archivo en algún lado, así que decidí hacerlo mediante jquery.

Guardado temporal:

```
var tmppath = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
```

De esa forma guardo temporalmente el archivo en algun lado del servidor y la ruta que me da es la siguiente:

```
blob:http://localhost:58145/ca3eca60-bdcb-4858-bf9f-76132569b9ef
```

Lo que eh intentado es abrirlo con el evento .open de `using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;` pero me marco un error.

Así que quería descargarlo en alguna carpeta local de mi proyecto para que ahí se vayan abriendo, esta es la instruccion:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.DownloadFile(urlExcel, "hola.xlsx");
}
```

pero me marco el siguiente error:

```
{"Acceso denegado a la ruta de acceso 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\IIS Express\\hola.xlsx'."}
```

También intente cambiando el ultimo parámetro por un folder pero siguió saliendo el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que tu programa tal vez no tiene derecho a escribir en ese directorio, intenta guardar el archivo en c:\temp o en algún otro directorio con ayuda de `Environment.GetFolderPath` y `Environment.SpecialFolder`.

Por ejemplo para guardarlo en el escritorio:

```
string desktopPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop);
```